# CSS animation jumps instead of infinite loop

Tags: html, css

My code looks like this.

```css
#workContainer {
  height: 500px;
}

#workContainer ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}

#workContainer li img {
  width: 200px;
}

#workContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#workContainerScroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: scrollText 10s infinite linear;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: fit-content;
}

#workContainerScroll li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-28%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="workContainer">
  <ul id="workContainerScroll">
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase1.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase2.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase3.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase4.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase5.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase6.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase7.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase8.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase9.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase10.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase11.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase12.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="assets/images/showcase/iPhoneShowcase13.png" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When the animation is near the end it just hops back to the start. How may I make it appear as an infinite scroll without the hop?

I've tried a few different approaches but this one was the one I got working as I wanted except from the jumping part at the end.

Comment: Have you tried using css modulus? [mod()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mod). At the moment it’s not widely supported but might be good taking a look to it.

Comment: read this; https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif I do not use Sass

Comment: I had this problem and solved it by duplicating a few of the first items, and having them occur at the end. So the series would be something like: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3`. The carousel DID technically shift back to the beginning, but the user never perceived a jump; to the user's eyes, it was an infinite loop. How many items do you duplicate? This depends on other factors.

Comment: you are not obliged to use Sass. Sass is used to make the code generic and easy to write but in the end it will compile to CSS. You have to use CSS in all the cases so either you write it manually or you generate it with Sass

Answer (score 1):

Although an elegant answer already commented by @TemaniAfif, another simple approach is to copy the entire `workContainerScroll` ( or at least a few of its parts as commented by @Kalnode ) and animate it separately.

```css
#workContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 414px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#workContainer ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.workContainerScroll {
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  animation: primary 5s linear infinite;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#original {
  animation: original 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes original {
  from {
    left: 0%
  }
  to {
    left: -100%
  }
}

#copy {
  animation: copy 5s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes copy {
  from {
    left: 0%
  }
  to {
    left: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<base href="https://www.iconarchive.com/download/i14263/hydrattz/multipurpose-alphabet/" />
<div id="workContainer">
  <ul id="original" class="workContainerScroll">
    <li><img src="Letter-A-black.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-B-gold.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-C-red.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-D-blue.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-E-lg.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-F-pink.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-G-orange.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-H-violet.48.png" /></li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="copy" class="workContainerScroll">
    <li><img src="Letter-A-black.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-B-gold.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-C-red.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-D-blue.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-E-lg.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-F-pink.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-G-orange.48.png" /></li>
    <li><img src="Letter-H-violet.48.png" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```