# How to make a continuous logo scroller?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have a logo scroller/carousel I built, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the logos repeat sooner so that there is not a gap between the last logo and repeated first logo. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm currently using this CSS for the animation:

HTML

```
<div class="logo-scroller-wrap">


  <div class="logo-scroller1" data-paused="false">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__row">
  
  <!--Image 1-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
   <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Xbox-1.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  
   <!--Image 2-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
   <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Wells-Fargo-1.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  
   <!--Image 3-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
   <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Walmart-1.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  
   <!--Image 4-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
   <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Verizon-1.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  
   <!--Image 5-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
   <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_UPS-1.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
   <!--Image 6-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
      <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
        <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_United-1.svg" alt="" /> 
      </div>
      
      
      </div>
      
      
      
       <!--Image 7-->
      <div class="logo-scroller__item">
      
      
      <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
        <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Tyson-1.svg" alt="" />
      </div>
      
      
      </div>
      
      
      
       <!--Image 8-->
      <div class="logo-scroller__item">
      
      
      <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
       <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Sony-1.svg" alt="" />
      </div>

      
      </div>
  
   <!--Image 9-->
 <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
   <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Playstation-1.svg" alt="" /> 
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  
   <!--Image 10-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
   <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Prevent-Cancer-1.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  
  </div>
  
  
  
   <!--Image 11-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
  <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
    <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Pfizer-1.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
  
  
  </div>

   <!--Image 12-->
   <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_P-and-G-1.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

     <!--Image 13-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Microsoft-36-1.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

        <!--Image 14-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Microsoft-20-1.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

        <!--Image 15-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Mars-1.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

        <!--Image 16-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_Loreal-1.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

        <!--Image 17-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_HR-Block-2.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

        <!--Image 18-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_HBO-1.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

        <!--Image 19-->
  <div class="logo-scroller__item">
  
  
    <div class="logo-scroller__logo">
     <img src="https://dynamikinfluence.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Our-Work-Logos_GM-1.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    
    </div>

  
  
  </div>
  
  
  
  </div>
  
  
   
  
  
  <!-- <div class="logo-scroller__actions">
   <button class="logo-scroller__pause">Pause</button>
  </div> -->
  
  
  </div>
```

CSS

```
 @-webkit-keyframes infiniteLogoScrollLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
  }

  @keyframes infiniteLogoScrollLeft {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
  }

.logo-scroller-wrap{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo-scroller1 .logo-scroller__row {
    display: flex;
    margin: 24px 0;
    height: 132px;
    animation-name: infiniteLogoScrollLeft;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 90s;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 4940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  
  .logo-scroller1 .logo-scroller__item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 5px;
  }

.logo-scroller__logo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 123px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
}
```

JS

```
    let logoScroller1 = document.querySelector('.logo-scroller1');
    var scroller1Rows = logoScroller1.querySelectorAll('.logo-scroller__row');

  scroller1Rows.forEach((row, rowNum) => {
      let scrollerItems = row.querySelectorAll('.logo-scroller__item');
      let scrollerDuration = 50;
    
      scrollerItems.forEach((scrollerItem, i) => {
        scrollerItem.style.animationDelay = 
          ((i * (-scrollerDuration / scrollerItems.length)) - (rowNum * 2)) + 's';
      });
    });
```

You can see it in action here: https://codepen.io/jfunchio/pen/rNRBjeB

Comment: I have added my code to the question here to reproduce the issues I am having.

Comment: read this: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation

Comment: May be this help: [CSS animation jumps instead of infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77509013/css-animation-jumps-instead-of-infinite-loop).

Answer (score 1):

Add your first logo as your last logo (so you have it twice), with a viewport that fits one logo (presumably, all of them are the same size. So you're using a CSS variable for that. If not, time to start doing that =).

Now scrolling X logos, with X+1 (because of the repeat at the end) elements, means scrolling by X * width. Because that will have scrolled the last element into view, and because that's also the first element, resetting the CSS animation won't visibly do anything, even though we reset the scroll position back to 0.

We've ensured that what the user sees at 0% is *visually identical* to what they see at X*width.

```css
:root {
  --logo-width: 100px;
}

@keyframes scrollContent {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: calc(-6 * var(--logo-width));
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--logo-width);
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  animation: scrollContent 5s linear infinite;
  height: 1em;
  width: calc(6 * var(--logo-width));
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: var(--logo-width);
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
  &:nth-child(2n) {
    background: gold;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <span>wow</span><span>look</span><span>at</span><span>this</span><span>text</span><span>dude</span><span>wow</span>
  </div>
</div>
```